# Linking Meshes on new scene, placement issue

Tags: mesh, linked-data, scene, collections, memory-management

I am trying to link a collection into a new scene. The collection has one mesh with its origin located at the centre of the grid. Still, when I link it to my new scene, the linked mesh looks far away from its empty/origin.

Original File:
[image]

Linked to New Scene:

[image]

How can I fix this? It is affecting my workflow considerably.

Thank you